# Ohm's law and rheostat relation

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

According to rheostat by increasing length potential increases and when potential increased then current also increases...but according to ohm,s law current decreases by increasing  voltage

Comment: Your question is unclear. Horrible spelling mistakes need to be done away with. The rheostat simply provides the resistance. The increase in the length of the wire increases the resistance offered by the rheostat. What does that have to do with voltage or current?

Comment: Current certainly does NOT decrease when the voltage is increased, according to Ohm's law. Sorry, but your question is totally unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

By Ohm's law, the current flowing is directly proportional to the potential difference. Not inversely.